# Question about injectivity of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M$ a module over it and $k_1,k_2$ fields such that we have the following maps $A \to k_1\to k_2$. Construct the natural map:
$$f: M\otimes_A k_1 \to M\otimes_A k_2.$$
If $m\in M$ is such that $m\otimes 1 = 0 \in M\otimes_A k_2$, does it follow that $m\otimes 1 = 0\in M\otimes_A k_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, because fields are flat. $M\otimes_A k_1$ is a $k_1$-vector space : call it $V$. Then your map is the extension of scalars $V\rightarrow V\otimes_{k_1} k_2$ which is injective (take a basis or whatever).